# Passing parameters to a method C++

Tags: c++, methods, parameters

I have experience in java and I have decided to look at C++. To do this, I thought I'd go through some early (basic) Java examples I have done before, and convert them into C++.
Basically I have two classes, 'main' and 'Conversion'

Conversion will convert imperial measurements to kilos.

main gets user input. What I'm trying to do, is pass 2 double values and two strings from main to a method in conversion `convert` but im getting the error

`missing ';' before ','` for the method call below ( unit1 and unit 2 are double variables) 
and then other two are strings

```
   Conversion.convert(unit1, unit2, sUnit1, sUnit2);
```

this is supposed to send the 4 parameters to this method in conversion.

```
void convert(double unit1, double unit2, std::string sUnit1, std::string sUnit2)
{
    double result1 = calculate(unit1, sUnit1);
    double result2 = calculate(unit2, sUnit2);
    print(result1+result2);
}
```

Any ideas why this throws an error? Also say if u need more code, I'm sure this is really obvious but maybe you can see from my code I'm more used to Java.

Comment: What is the line before the one with `Conversion.convert`?

Comment: you should give us the code of `calculate` and `print` ! you gave us no info.

Comment: Actually, you should give us a *minimal, complete example*. This applies to all languages, not just C++.

Comment: ok i dont know much about c++, but i know about programming and having the code for print and calculate bare no meaning to this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot call methods on classes like that. Either `convert` is a static method, in which case you call it like this:

```
Conversion::convert(unit1, unit2, sUnit1, sUnit2);
```

or it is a member function, in which case you need to call it on an instance of `Conversion`:

```
Conversion c;
c.convert(unit1, unit2, sUnit1, sUnit2);
```

Note that, unlike Java, in C++ you can have "free" functions, i.e. you do not have to place them inside a class. The common practice in these cases is to put functions in namespaces:

```
namespace Conversions
{
   void convert(double d1, double d2, std::string s1, std::string s2) { ... }
}
```

You can then call it similarly to the static method case:

```
Conversions::convert(unit1, unit2, sUnit1, sUnit2);
```

Also note that, unless you are going to make copies of the `std::strings` you are passing to the function, it is better to pass by const reference to avoid unnecessary copies:

```
void convert(double d1, double d2, const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2);
```

The same applies to the doubles, you can pass them by const reference, but it is hardly worth it given the cost of potentially copying a double.

Finally, [`main`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function) is the name of a very special function in C++ and C, so you should avoid using it for class names. It is not a keyword, but it could be confusing nonetheless.

Comment: thank you very much exactly what i was looking for, as i said i dont have a lot of experience and am just starting looking at c++ and by the look of it just tried to be a bit too java with Conversion.convert

Comment: @AngryDuck The languages are quite different, although the syntax can be deceptively similar. Learn about references, `const`, and remember that you do not need to type `new` hardly ever.

Comment: yea i know i have done a bit of C++ before but it was a couple of years ago now. i know i dont use new and i need to remember to destroy things that i create. ill look into const tho cheers for the info...

Comment: @AngryDuck you only need to remember to destroy things if you create them with `new` or `malloc`. So the name of the game is to not have to worry about that.

Comment: malloc meaning? or is it best to not know then i wont end up using it :P

Comment: @AngryDuck best not to know! It is a C thing.

Comment: ha ok yea dont wanna go into C yet still need to get the hang of this c++ thing yet